# Chromecast 4 not connecting to the second router via WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge, chromecast

I have two routers. The first router is connected to the Internet with the first Loco M2 as an access point and the second one is connected with the second Loco M2 wifi bridge. The second Loco M2 is connected to the second router through the WAN port.

The first router IP (ISP): **192.168.1.1**
Subnet: **255.255.255.0**

The second router IP(Asus TUF-AX5400): **192.167.1.1**
Subnet: **255.255.255.0**
DNS: **192.168.1.1**
Gateway: **192.168.1.1**

I connect phones or laptops to the second router by ethernet or wifi and there is no problem. The problem starts when I want to connect Chromecast 4 to wifi. The wifi is visible, and the signal is strong, but when I press connect, it shows that it tries to connect and after a while, it displays information that it cannot find the network.
I have the same problem with other smart devices.

The only way I can connect Chromecast is by connecting it to the first Loco antenna that works as an access point. But the signal there is not ideal.

Is there an option inside router settings that doesn't allow smart devices and Chromecast to connect to wifi?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The second router IP(Asus TUF-AX5400): 192.167.1.1

I am quite sure 192.167 is a typo but then the second router cannot have the same address as the first router.

**You can solve the problem this way:**

Hook up a LAN port on the second router to a LAN port on the first router. Do this with Ethernet, not Wireless.

Give the second router a static IP address on the first router (likely 192.168.1.11 should work).

In the settings of the second router, turn DHCP OFF (you cannot have two DHCP servers on the same network).

Comment: It's not a typo. I have 192.167.1.1.

I have this configuration:
Router1 > LAN > Loco M2 (Access point) <-> Loco M2 (station) > WAN > router.
Should I change 192.167.1.1 to 192.168.1.11 and attach it to LAN instead of WAN + turn off DHCP?
I'll try it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I made changes:
192.167.1.1 to 192.168.1.11
Second Loco M2 attached to LAN instead of WAN
DHCP from ON to OFF

Reset router and Chromecast
It works exactly the same as before. Laptops and phones can connect to Wifi, but Chromecast can't
BTW. I can't connect routers by ethernet that's why I made a wifi bridge with Locos.

Comment: Perhaps try a different router. What I described is a workable and robust approach that I have use for many years.